# When and How did Luffy get the Scar under his eye?

Tags: one-piece

Luffy has a pretty prominent scar under his Eye.

Its been a long time since I started watching One Piece, and *I seem to recall that he stabbed himself to have Shanks take him onboard as a pirate.* Recently, though I started rewatching the series (Oh... The nostalgia!!) but there was no such scene in the flashback.

**When and how did he get the scar under his eye?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He did get it the way you described. In Chapter One of the Manga he stab himself with a dagger in the eye to prove himself.

[image]

It's the same story in the anime. Although as noted in the comments from Bálint its missing from every anime series except in the TV special titled "Episode of Luffy"

Comment: Thank you for this image from the Manga.